# Additional Buckets are seen in metrics explorer compared with Google Cloud storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

1. There are few additional bucket information available in metric explorer when compared with cloud storage bucket explore. This seems to be old deleted bucket. However, it appears in Metric explorer. Is there any reason why it is appearing here ?
2. Also there are some buckets seen in storage explorer but not shown in metrics explorer. Please note this was not created before 24 hours. It is there for quite some time

Comment: Hey @Sunil, I have posted an answer. Can you check if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question -

As mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/latency-n-retention#metric-retention) -

> Cloud Monitoring acquires metric data and holds it in the time series of metric types for a period of time. This period of time varies with the metric type; See Data retention for details.

> At the end of that period, Monitoring deletes the expired data points.

> When all the points in a time series have expired, Monitoring deletes the time series. Deleted time series do not appear in Monitoring charts or in results from the Monitoring API.

Here as you are talking about the Cloud Storage metrics which come under [Google Cloud metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-storage) and as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas#data_retention_policy) the data retention period is 6 weeks for Google Cloud metrics. So if you have deleted the bucket within the past 6 weeks the data for that bucket will show up in the metrics explorer.

To answer your second question -

Which bucket will be shown in the metrics explorer depends on the metrics you are using. If any bucket doesn’t have any relevant data for that metric it will not show up there. Let's say if you have a bucket but you don’t have any object inside that bucket. So if you explore with the Object count(storage/object_count) metric then that bucket will not show up in the metrics explorer. So I will suggest you try with some other metrics i.e. Sent bytes or Received bytes or Log entries which are mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-storage). Also the metrics have different measuring times. So based on the metrics you may need to wait for some time to get the data in metrics explorer.