# GCS Bucket is empty but metrics explorer shows important amount of bytes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have an empty bucket :

[image: empty_bucket]

But the metric explorer says there are 5Gib of storage used :

[image: metr]

Is there some cache mechanism for deleted objects somehow that we don't know ? If i click on `Show deleted objects` from the GCS bucket it doesn't show anything.

Thanks in advance if you know the cause / how can i make sure the bucket is empty without deleting it since it was created by Google i prefer keep it unless i have no choice of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is intended behavior, As mentioned in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71844392/18265638) by prabir

> Cloud Monitoring acquires metric data and holds it in the time series of metric types for a period of time. This period of time varies with the metric type; See [Data retention](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas#data_retention_policy) for details.
>
> At the end of that period, Monitoring deletes the expired data points.
>
> When all the points in a time series have expired, Monitoring deletes the time series. Deleted time series do not appear in Monitoring charts or in results from the Monitoring API.

> Cloud Storage metrics which comes under [Google Cloud metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-storage) and as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas#data_retention_policy) the data retention period is 6 weeks for Google Cloud metrics. So if you have deleted the bucket data within the past 6 weeks the data for that bucket will show up in the metrics explorer.

Comment: Oh thanks for your answer, i didn't know that but it makes sense. 
I guess it's the same for the Firebase console storage viewer in that case, because i was looking at the "Usage and billing" and still able to see the aditionnal GB that do not exist :)